# JNI , call boolean method

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I got a Java method that get a `String` and returns `boolean`.

I call it from JNI like this:

```
jmethodID function2ID = env->GetMethodID(
                    activityClass,
                    "MyFuncName",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)B");
        if ( function2ID == null )
            LOG("Could not find MyFuncName Function")

            jboolean IsAutoPlay =    env->CallBooleanMethod(
                    obj,
                    function2ID,
                    env->NewStringUTF(name));
```

I get Fatal Signal 11, Any idea what's wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My Java signature was to return `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Also

```
jmethodID function2ID = env->GetMethodID(
                    activityClass,
                    "MyFuncName",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)B");
```

needs to be `Z` instead of `B`.

```
jmethodID function2ID = env->GetMethodID(
                    activityClass,
                    "MyFuncName",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
```