# Sending a POJO from C to Java in a method call

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am currently working with JNI and I need to pass a Java Object from C to Java layer.
But I am not sure if this approach is correct.

I have a Java POJO or model class which contains geo location data:

```
public class Geoloc{
 private double latitude;
 pivate double longitude;
 public Geoloc(double latitude, double longitude){
   this.longitude = longitude;
   this.latitude = latitude;
 }
 public double getLatitude(){
    return this.latitude;
 }
 public double getLongitude(){
    return this.longitude;
 }

 public void setLatitude(double lat){
  this.latitude = lat;
 }
 public void setLongitude(double longitude){
  this.longitude = longitude;
 }
}
```

My C function looks something like

```
void jni_inc_msg_ind_cbk(...)
{

jclass c = (*envPtr)->FindClass(envPtr, "com/my/geoloc/Geoloc");
        if (c == 0) {
            ret_val = 0;
        }else{
            printf("Found class.\n");
        }
        cnstrctr = (*envPtr)->GetMethodID(envPtr, c, "<init>", "(DD)V");
        jgeoloc = (*envPtr)->NewObject(envPtr, c, cnstrctr, jlatitude, 

jlongitude);
incChatMethodId = (*envPtr)->GetMethodID(envPtr,ojb, "incChatSessInd",
            "????");
            (*envPtr)->CallVoidMethod(envPtr, p_pdb->objct, incChatMethodId,jgeoloc);
    }
```

So my question is are the below two statements a valid call, also what is the exact parameter that needs to be passed to replace "????"

```
incChatSessIndMethodId = (*envPtr)->GetMethodID(envPtr,ojb, "incChatSessInd",
            "????");
 (*envPtr)->CallVoidMethod(envPtr, p_pdb->objct, incChatSessIndMethodId,jgeoloc);
```

If I am unable to call the java method with a java pojo argument I would need to add around 20 arguments to the actual implementation. Which would be quite bizzare.

Comment: Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257755/jni-call-boolean-method - if that solves it for you we should probably mark this a duplicate.

Comment: Chris, this answer has a method call with a return type,while I want to call a java method with an object as argument.

Comment: Please re-read it as that example is passing an object (specifically a String) as an argument.

Comment: yes, but my case has a complex object/ custom object though, are you saying I should replace the "Ljava/lang/String;" with "Lcom/my/geoloc/Geoloc;" The thing is I cant run this code, because I still dont have the library which will send me the geo location for a few days (being developed by another team)

Comment: Yes, I think that is what you should do. You may not have the real library, but it looks like you have enough representative code of it to try passing around its objects, if you just add a little code to create them using fixed or random test values.

Comment: Just tried it, MethodId is null in this case. :(

Comment: Then either that method doesn't exist in your Java code yet, or you mis-specified it.  Edit your question to include the java code of the method (showing containing package and class information), and to show the exact native call you made in an attempt to retrieve it.  You might also want to add a dummy method alongside that takes a String as an argument and try to get that one first as a stepping-stone test towards your goal.

Comment: I just remembered this now, and it did not work the methodId returned was null. in this case. Had to add a whole bunch of arguments to my method. :(